# How can I pass addition local object variable to my event handler?

Tags: c#, silverlight, events, handler

I want to a pass local object to the event handler. How can I do that? For example, how can I reference the "graphic" object, which is declared in the main function below, in the event handler function "hyperlinkButton_Click"?

```
    void main()
    {
        Graphic graphic = new Graphic();

        hyperlinkButton.Click+=new RoutedEventHandler(hyperlinkButton_Click);
    }

    void hyperlinkButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use a delegate or a lambda expression.

```
hyperlinkButton.Click += (sender, e) => HandleGraphic(graphic, sender, e);
```

Comment: Bless you God, good man!

Answer (score 1):

You could try closing on the `graphic` variable:

```
void main()
{
    Graphic graphic = new Graphic();

    hyperlinkButton.Click += (sender, e) => 
    {
        graphic.Blah(); 
    };
}
```

This would not be a good idea if you eventually need to remove the event handler manually.  Alternatively, you could make `graphic` a field instead of a local variable.

Answer (score 1):

```
   void main()
    {
        Graphic graphic = new Graphic();
        hyperlinkButton.Tag = graphic;
        hyperlinkButton.Click+=new RoutedEventHandler(hyperlinkButton_Click);
    }

    void hyperlinkButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       Graphic graphic =(sender as HyperlinkButton).Tag as Graphic;
    }
```

but not good way.